# Common definitions of graphical items in Modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola

I could see there are some common definitions of the graphical items in Modelica language, but I can't find the definitions in Modelica Standard Library, so these definitions are built-in types?

[image]

Comment: Ok, after reading it a second time, the answer is yes: the definitions of the graphical primitives in the Modelica Specification are built-in types, you cannot see them anywhere in any library except maybe some inside the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types, *and* the records in that chapter, are internal to the specification.

Additionally having `unit="mm`" as for DrawingUnit is not recommended for normal types, as the idea is to use SI-types *without any prefix*.